# update to mvc 5.2.3.0 results in ValidationMessageFor containing empty messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

The fiddler output for my page prior to the latest update of MVC produces this html.

```
   <div class="text-danger">
     <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Person.Initials" data-valmsg-replace="true">  
     &#39;Initials &#39; should not be empty.</span>
   </div>
```

The output after updating the packages is as follows.

```
  <div class="text-danger">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Person.FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
```

The span no longer contains the error message?

*Just to be clear, all the error messages on all the models are doing the same thing, this is not specific to one particular field.*

The configuration file has not changed, and has the lines below:
**If I remove** `ClientValidationEnabled` **from the configuration file the old (correct?) HTML is produced.**

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

I have edited the post to include the model below.

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name = "person", Namespace = "http://palantir.aureus.co.za/data/investor")]
    public partial class Person : Party
    {
        #region Constructor(s)
        /// <summary>
        /// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="Person"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        [DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public Person()
        {
            this.PartyType = PartyType.Person;
            this.OnCreated();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="Person"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tenant">The tenant.</param>
        public Person(Tenant tenant) : this() 
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(tenant != null);
            this.TenantId = tenant.Id;
            this.Tenant = tenant;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the <c>FirstName for the Person</c>.
        /// </summary>      
        [DataMember(Name = "firstName", IsRequired = true)]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Given Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the <c>Surname for the Person</c>.
        /// </summary>      
        [DataMember(Name = "surname", IsRequired = true)]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Family Name")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the <c>Initials for the Person</c>.
        /// </summary>      
        [DataMember(Name = "initials", IsRequired = true)]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Initials ")]
        public string Initials { get; set; }

}
```

I have updated all packages to the latest version, MVC was on 5.2.2.0